# Add class to parent tag if parent has some class

Tags: jquery, class, addclass

I have a some jQuery code:

```
jQuery('li:has(.selected)').addClass('test');
```

and I need to add class to `li` if `li` has `a` with class `.selected`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I need to add class to LI if LI has A with class .selected

So the `li` will have an `a.selected` in it? Then:

```
jQuery("a.selected").parent("li").addClass("test");
```

or possibly

```
jQuery("li > a.selected").parent().addClass("test");
```

or if you really mean ancestor, not parent:

```
jQuery("li a.selected").closest('li').addClass("test");
```

More:

- [`parent`](http://api.jquery.com/parent)
- [`closest`](http://api.jquery.com/closest)
- [child combinator](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#child-combinators)
- [descendant combinator](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#descendant-combinators)

Comment: Something like this 
<li class="test"><a class="selected">Link</a></li>

Comment: @Oleg: Then the above will work. That's a parent/child relationship.

Comment: Hm.. I try to use this code. But when page is load, code don't work. Only if I use this code in console. <script type="text/javascript">
                        jQuery(document).ready(function () {
                            jQuery("li > a.selected").parent().addClass("test")
                        });
                    </script>

Comment: @Oleg: The elements have to exist before you can operate on them. That means either putting your script at the end of the HTML (just before the closing `</body>` tag), which is generally best, or using `ready`.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$(function() {
    $('li').has('a.selected').addClass('test');
});
```

http://api.jquery.com/has/

Another easy thing would be to just select the a itself:

```
$(function() {
    $('a.selected').parent('li').addClass('test');
});
```

Comment: youre right, i updated my answer. that was the method i looked up before *shame*